# how to stop gridview.builder from generating items in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am new to flutter and I want to stop `GridView.builder` from scrolling after the elements is finished .

**EX:** I have a **list** of 9 items and I want the `gridView.builder` to create only 9 items=**>list.length**.

here the code **=>the list**

```
List<Map<String, Object>> values = [
  { "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},{ "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},{ "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},{ "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},{ "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},{ "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},{ "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},{ "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},{ "id":0,
    "category":"موبيلات",
    'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
    'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},
  ];
```

and here the **=>GridView**

```
GridView.builder(gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount:2,mainAxisSpacing: 2,), itemBuilder: (BuildContext,i){

                        for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){
                      return
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 400,
                            width: 200,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: (){},
                              child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                      child: Image.asset(values[i]['categorybackimage'],fit: BoxFit.fill, )),
                                    Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text("${(values[i]['category'])}"),

                                   Card(
                                     color: Colors.white,
                                     child: Text(
                                        "عروض ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.red,
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),

                                      ),
                                   ),
                                  Image.asset(values[i]['categoryimage'],)
                                ],
                              ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                    }}),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `itemCount` property in `GridView.builder` set that to the length of your list.

```
GridView.builder(gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount:2,mainAxisSpacing: 2,), 
itemCount:list.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext,i){ return YourAwesomeWidget(); });
```

also you don't have to use a for loop inside your `itembuilder` funtion, the gridview builder can loop through your list without any additional code.